# Capture video using FFMPEG without frozen image effect

Tags: ffmpeg, frame, capture

Anyone could help me? Have been trying to record video from an RTSP server using FFMPEG but somehow the video result has many frozen images (couldn't be used for any people detection) - the people look similar to this:
[image]

Here is the code I used:

> ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.10.10.10/encoder1 -b:v 1024k -s 640x480 -an -t 60 -r 12.5 output.mp4

What I have done so far?
- Recorded the video in smaller dimension instead of original one
- No audio and lower FPS
- Even only record from two IP sources on a machine

But still didn't get any luck yet. Anyone ever experience this?

Comment: Does anything, such as a player, decode it without errors/artifacts?

Comment: Try to play in MPlayer so that you can confirm whether it is an issue in decoding or it is an issue in rendering.